# Can anyone recommend a good c++ convex hull shape/area library?

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I've been using `boost::geometry`, but it's still a young project and has a few too many bugs at the moment.  Doubtless these will be fixed one day but is there a better choice right now?

EDIT: the bugs that were troubling me are now fixed - back on boost::geometry.

Comment: Did you have a look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)?

Comment: Looks good, but not as free as boost (I need commercial license, expensive).

Comment: Take a look at [qhull]. It's stable, used in projects such as the [Point Cloud Library][pcl]. [qhull]: http://www.qhull.org/
[pcl]: http://pointclouds.org

Comment: @SideshowBob There are several licenses and you should check which one really applies to you.

Comment: Aah, now that's free as in beer AND software (also as in boost).  Will have to give it a try.

Comment: FWIW the boost team have fixed a few bugs lately.  Still doesn't compile under intel/windows but might be working properly on msvc, I intend to find out in the next few days.