# Is there any selection finding all minimum closed polygons formed by random lines besides CGAL?

Tags: c++, graphics, polygon, cgal

I work in 2D.

I need to find the minimum closed polygon formed by a set of random lines.

It seems CGAL may solve this problem, but CGAL is huge, full of templates and a little hard to use.

Is there any selection besides CGAL?

Comment: There are some recommendations here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990492/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-c-convex-hull-shape-area-library.

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more? Do you just want the convex hull of the end points of the lines? Also a hint for CGAL, you can use it in header only mode! Put the #define CGAL_HEADER_ONLY (not 100% sure, something like that) and no need for a lib. You may have to also generate the config header with cmake. You still need boost though :/

Comment: Also, maybe check out http://gts.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @starmole thank you for your help. I want the every polygons formed by set of random lines, not the convex hull. I need to find out polygons witch does not have any  more little polygons inside. Just like every room which closed by a set of walls. And i m now trying header only mode of CGAL.

Comment: Maybe add an image of input and expected result to your question. I am still not sure I completely understand it. Maybe there is some basic algorithm you can implement yourself.

Comment: @starmole I have tried CGAL and i found the arrangement_2d module of CGAL seems could solve my problem. I can insert segments (i dont need curves) and get all the bounded faces with its points in arrangement. I think this could be a good result for my problem. The sulotion should act like : INPUT 4 lines ( as exsample, 3 lines formed a triangle , the last line split triangle into a little triangle and a 4-edges polygon ) OUTPUT 3 points of the triangle and 4 point of the 4 edges polygon.

Comment: @starmole oh, it's a little hard to post a test code in here , so i post some my test code in [github](https://github.com/0871087123/test_arr_cgal/tree/master)